# Styled components - Trying to access json by a different key name

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, styled-components

```js
import styled from "vue-styled-components";
const props = { type: String, action: Boolean };

const getter = () => {
  const permissionsList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("UZ")).permissions;
  const type = props.type;
  const action = props.action;

  return permissionsList.type.action;
};

export const stylePermission = styled("span")`
  pointer-events: ${getter() ? "" : "none"};
  cursor: ${getter() ? "pointer" : "not-allowed"};
  opacity: ${getter() ? 1 : 0.4};
`;
```

I am using it like this

```js
<template slot="tab-head-roles">
   <sp-permission type="user" action="can_approve">
      <router-link to="/settings/roles">Roles</router-link>
   </sp-permission>
</template>
```

I am unable to access `return permissionsList.type.action;` because `type` and `action` does not exist in the JSON Object but the value of `type` and `action` exists in the object.

What is the best way for me to access it.

Comment: probably with the correct property name?

Comment: I can not use the correct property name because it is dynamic.

Comment: What is the value that you are getting for `localStorage.getItem("UZ")` ?

Comment: In that case you can never know what property value you need. If the structure of your object is different every time, you will not get consistent results

Comment: @stud3nt I am getting a json object

Comment: @NodeShack well yes, but you don't know it's members, so how do you expect to get the values of those members then?

Comment: @NodeShack Please log the value of `localStorage.getItem("UZ")` and share it in the question. and not just the value type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use square brackets to use the value of `type` and `action` as key names:-

```
const getter = () => {
  const permissionsList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("UZ")).permissions;
  const type = props.type;
  const action = props.action;

  return permissionsList[type][action];
};
```

Comment: I tried this. but I am getting this error

```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'function Boolean() { [native code] }' of undefined```

Comment: Try doing `console.log(permissionsList[type][action])` and see what value you are getting. And also can show a sample of permissionsList?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it

```js
import styled from "vue-styled-components";
const permissionProps = { type: String, action: String };

const getter = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("UZ")).permissions;

export const stylePermission = styled("span", permissionProps)`
  pointer-events: ${props => (getter[props.type][props.action] ? "" : "none")};
  cursor: ${props =>
    getter[props.type][props.action] ? "pointer" : "not-allowed"};
  opacity: ${props => (getter[props.type][props.action] ? 1 : 0.4)};
`;
```